# Handling synchronous methods in async/await best practices (turtles all the way down)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

With async turtles all the way down ...

Some of the background research:

- [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)
- [Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

In code I've seen:

- Developers wrap code in a Task.Run() upon entering a method and awaiting it to force it to be async or (or older .NET 4.0 TaskFactory.StartNew())
- I've personally just left it synchronous (but it partially violates turtles all the down as different branches often are sync)
- I've also seen the attempt to use [ValueTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=netcore-3.1) to short-circuit the return as async given the nature of ValueTask with a return value being akin to:

```
return new ValueTask<int>(valueWantToReturn);
```

Example psudeo code:

```
     public async Task ParentMethodAsync()
    {
     // ... do something upon entering
     int neededValue = SyncNestedDryMethod(); // ** this part **

     await _nthLayer.DoSomethingWithRepoAsync(); // ** same concept applies here 
     //                 if there is no asyncronous logic required **

     // ... do anything else needed
    }

    public int SyncNestedDryMethod()
    {
      // ... do something that requires no real async method signature 
      // declaration because it is straight synchronous logic (covers reusing 
      // code for DRY purposes, method-level SRP abstraction (includes moving it 
      // to an abstracted class -- for future readers), etc.)

      // I've seen making the method async then awaiting Task.Run() or 
      // Task.StartFactory.New() inside this (sync changed to async method) 
      // to try and force it to be async or last line being: 
      //       return new ValueTask<int>(valueWantToReturn);
      // but everything above it being only syncronous logic
    }
```

Is there a best practice to be aware of not found addressed in the respective links (or overlooked) or elsewhere which I have not come across to address abstracting synchronous code into new methods (for DRY purposes, SRP, etc.) that do not have the ability to be async or are forced async all the while following async through and through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think you're asking how to run synchronous code in an asynchronous way? If so, the answer is: you can't.

Using `Task.Run()` doesn't make the code asynchronous. It just runs the code on a different thread and gives you an asynchronous way to wait for that thread to complete. That may be what you need if you just need to get the work off of the current thread. For example, you would use that in a desktop application where you want to get the work off of the UI thread. But this wouldn't help you at all in ASP.NET.

`ValueTask` is used for cases where the work *might* be done asynchronously, but also may complete synchronously too. For example, if data is usually returned from an in memory cache, but refreshing that cache is done asynchronously. This is described in detail [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/). But if the work is *always* synchronous, then there is no point using `ValueTask`, or `Task` or `async`.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description, I have updated my post for future readers and added a psuedo code example. Your last sentence summarizes how I have been doing it to date, and what I'm looking to confirm/reconfirm as what was the best practice for this type of scenario given the subscribed 'turtles all the way down' Microsoft docs best practices statement coupled with having seen other developers code attempting to force synchronous methods to be asynchronous.

Comment: The only "best" practice is for the code to be asynchronous to begin with. You simply cannot "force" synchronous code to be asynchronous. If you can't rewrite the code to be asynchronous, then the only way to use it is to just run it normally, or to run it on a separate thread (`Task.Run`) if you don't want it to run on the current thread.

Comment: Thanks. When you have an asynchronous Web API, for example, and are building out a layer which would be the better choice?:    `public async Task SyncMethodTurnedIntoAsync() { await Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("I am now async"); }); }` _or_

`public void NormalSyncMethod() => Console.WriteLine("I am sync");` (ignoring consideration to expression-bodies member syntax for brevity)

PS, I would add +1 for the comment as it is helpful but don't have enough points currently

Comment: For any ASP.NET application, there is never a good reason to use `await Task.Run()`. It moves the execution to a ThreadPool thread, but you're already on a ThreadPool thread, so there's no point. The only effect is the added overhead of creating the task.